# js loop for of record (react/typescript)

Tags: reactjs, for-loop, object

I have several records{} with a lot of different data, where I need to get one which is object too. Can't make two different for loop :( anyone has an idea ?

my every record: RaRecord is an object

```
{sku: 1, name: 'TB', extended: {status : YES, element: 2} }
{sku: 2, name: 'EB', extended: {status : No, element: 4} }
{sku: 3, name: 'SB', extended: {status : No, element: 6} }
```

In the end I need to get an array of values of stock, like this:

```
stock = [2, 4, 6]
```

Comment: for (let i = 0; i < records.length; i++) {
  stockValues.push(records[i].extended.stock);
}

Comment: YES and NO should be `true` and `false` by the way, before you spend one afternoon debugging a bug in the future!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like your JSON has some issues but here is an example that should get you through

```js
const data = [{sku: 1, name: 'TB', extended: {availability : 'YES', stock: 2} },
{sku: 1, name: 'TB', extended: {availability : 'NO', stock: 4} }]

const result = data.map(item => item.extended.stock);
console.log(result)


//if you want only available == yes
const result2 = data.filter(item => item.extended.availability === 'YES').map(item => item.extended.stock);
console.log(result2)
```